# Pythonic way of creating new numpy array by unpacking a packed rgb numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array of shape `(N,)` which contains N packed rgb values using the following formulation-

```
rgb = (r<<16) + (g<<8) + b
```

I am trying to unpack this array and then create a `numpy` array of shape `(N,3)` by using unpacked values. See below the code snippet-

```
import numpy as np
def unpack_rgb(rgb):
    b =  rgb & 255
    g = (rgb >> 8) & 255
    r =   (rgb >> 16) & 255
    return r, g, b

N = 10
c = (np.ones((N, 3)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
for i in range(N):
    c[i, 0], c[i, 1], c[i, 2] = unpack_rgb(colors[i])
```

As shown above, `unpack_rgb` is used inside a `for` loop to assign color values to numpy array `c`. **I am looking for the pythonic way to unpack and create a new numpy array.**

The variable `colors` can be obtained by the following code-

```
from random import randint
def pack_rgb(r, g, b):
    rgb = (r<<16) + (g<<8) + b
    return rgb

colors = np.array([pack_rgb(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(N)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the bitwise operators on the whole numpy array, and then use `np.dstack` to get the (r, g, b) tuples, like:

```
unpacked_colors = ((colors >> 16) & 255, (colors >> 8) & 255, colors & 255)
rgbs = np.dstack(unpacked_colors)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `c` is useless? Just use your tuples in default `np.array` constructor

```
np.array([unpack_rgb(colors[_]) for _ in range(N)])

array([[203, 157, 217],
       [169, 143,  86],
       [192, 127,   8],
       [114,  32, 141],
       [153,  39,   1],
       [ 14,  17,  57],
       [200,  72, 146],
       [133, 173, 139],
       [ 35,  88,  40],
       [ 22,  38, 144]], dtype=uint8)
```